# gfsh create command region-time-to-live not working as expected

Tags: ttl, gemfire, geode, gfsh

When I `create` a region using the following command and use `describe` afterwards, it doesn't show me `region-time-to-live` settings **at all**. Only when I use `alter` I can see the `entry-time-to-live` and `region-time-to-live` to be set properly.

```
gfsh>create region --name=myRegion --type=REPLICATE --enable-statistics=true --entry-time-to-live-expiration=200 --region-time-to-live-expiration=2000

gfsh>describe region --name
Region | entry-time-to-live.timeout | 2000
       | data-policy                | REPLICATE
       | size                       | 0
       | statistics-enabled         | true
       | scope                      | distributed-ack


gfsh>alter region --name=myRegion --entry-time-to-live-expiration=200 --region-time-to-live-expiration=2000

gfsh>describe region --name
Region | entry-time-to-live.timeout | 200
       | data-policy                | REPLICATE
       | region-time-to-live.timeout| 2000
       | size                       | 0
       | statistics-enabled         | true
       | scope                      | distributed-ack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this bug was already solved in the latest `develop` branch from GEODE, specifically through [GEODE-1897](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-1897). Below is the output I see:

```
    _________________________     __
   / _____/ ______/ ______/ /____/ /
  / /  __/ /___  /_____  / _____  / 
 / /__/ / ____/  _____/ / /    / /  
/______/_/      /______/_/    /_/    1.5.0-SNAPSHOT

Monitor and Manage Apache Geode
gfsh>start locator --name=locator1

gfsh>start server --name=server1

gfsh>create region --name=myRegion --type=REPLICATE --enable-statistics=true --entry-time-to-live-expiration=200 --region-time-to-live-expiration=2000
Member  | Status
------- | ---------------------------------------
server1 | Region "/myRegion" created on "server1"

gfsh>describe region --name=/myRegion
..........................................................
Name            : myRegion
Data Policy     : replicate
Hosting Members : server1

Non-Default Attributes Shared By Hosting Members  

 Type  |            Name             | Value
------ | --------------------------- | ---------------
Region | entry-time-to-live.timeout  | 200
       | data-policy                 | REPLICATE
       | region-time-to-live.timeout | 2000
       | size                        | 0
       | scope                       | distributed-ack
       | statistics-enabled          | true
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way for me to know which Gemfire version this fix would be a part of??

Comment: I'd say that, probably, this will be shipped in next major GemFire release: `9.3.0`.